# Ruby in Rails - Activeadmin - :filter Age from Birthday column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter, activeadmin

I have a little problem. In my DB I have a column `:birthday`. Format is `Date: "1999-12-1"` for example. But I want to have a filter for age in my page.

Is there an easy way to calculate it ?
filter `:birthday.age` or something? I know this sounds easy, but I can't make it work.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't say 'easy', but there are a couple of articles on custom filters with Ransack listed on the [wiki](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/wiki#index-pages-filters-and-scopes).